# Why is the question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78213/which-one-is-grammatically-correct

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78214/which-one-is-grammatically-correct

I worked hard trying to come up with some things that's grammatically correct. So I ask which one is grammatically correct. There are many similar questions. So what's wrong?

I love learning all languages. Programming languages and english language is one of them. So I want to know some detail. Which one is an adjective. Which one is a noun. Why something is wrong.

Actually, what is different between those 2 questions and other questions asking for grammar?

Is this because I use too many samples?

Comment: Please give examples of open question like yours.

Comment: While asking on meta is the correct course of action, it should be pointed out that some reasons were given in the comments on your questions, by mods and regular users alike. I am saying that because after checking your post history I can't shake off that weird feeling that you often overlook what others post. (You'll ask a question, get an answer, *accept* it, and then ask the exact same question right back in the comments; things like that.)

Comment: did I? I sometimes comment to ask for clarification of the question. Some answers to those 2 questions are great though.

Answer (score 6):

Your question about *still* seems to be more about the meaning of the word, than any kind of grammar, since you don't understand the meaning of the word.

The steps to asking a good meaning question:

1. Look up your word in a dictionary.
2. Take time to understand what the dictionary entry is telling you.
3. If there are still things you don't understand, ask your question including:

   - explaining what research you have done
   - explaining why this doesn't answer your question
   - clearly ask about the thing you don't understand, including context as necessary.
4. Come up with a good title for your question, something that is specific to your problem.
5. Tag appropriately

Your other questions is just a list of sentences and the question "Which, if any, are correct?" For one, proof reading is off topic (see the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq)), for another you don't explain why any should be correct or incorrect.

Your questions demonstrate that you are still learning English. That's great, we're all still learning to some degree. But you seem to be towards the beginning end of the learning spectrum, whereas questions on this site should come from people who already know the language quite well. We're not here to teach people English. This is why there is a proposal for an [English language learner's Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners), to complement this site and allow people a place to ask questions that are too basic for here.